# Success of Bernoulli trials with different probabilities, but a probability is only changed after success

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

**I would like to compute the Bernoulli trials with different probabilities, but the probability is only changed after success.**

Such as here, all probability, p, is different at each state, s, in the figure below; s: (0, 1, ..., m).
The figure is the representation of the Bernoulli trials.

[image]

The trial will start from the state (0).
Then, $p_0$ is a prob. of success in state (0).

If we succeed, then $p_1$ will be used for the next trial.
Here, the random variable $X_k$ denotes the number of successes in k trials.

**How to derive $Pr[X_k=i]$ in a simpler way?
I refer to the Poisson Binomial Distribution, but it seems a little bit different.
i is the successful outcome with k trials.**

Currently, I derive below.

$Pr[X_k=0] = p_0^0 \times (1-p_0)^{(k-0)}$.
That is, the number of successes is zero, so it fails for every $k$ trial, i.e., stays at the first state (0) in all $k$ trials.
$Pr[X_k=1] = p_0^1 \times (\text{Sum of all combinations of failures, $1-p_0$, $1-p_1$ with k-1 trials})$.
Here, the number of successes is one, so it succeeds one time at the state (0), and fails in $k-1$ trials.

Actually, my goal is to derive
$Pr[X_k<m] (=Pr[X_k=0]+Pr[X_k=1]+...+Pr[X_k=m-1])$, which is the probability of failures to reach the state (m).

- The above image is from the paper (M. Kleinbort, K. Solovey, Z. Littlefield, K. E. Bekris and D. Halperin, "**Probabilistic Completeness of RRT for Geometric and Kinodynamic Planning With Forward Propagation**") but modified it by myself with different probabilities.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE! when asking [good questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it might help to provide some context about this problem, eg. where did this image come from, or is it your original creation? Also, what is the RV $X$? Do you mean $X$ is the position of the state after $n$ trials, where $n$ is fixed? Or is $X$ the stopping time before the state reaches a set position $m$? As it stands, it's not possible to help you as your question is unclear.

Comment: I reflected on it and made them as clear as possible! Thank you for pointing out :)

Comment: Following your edit - are you asking for the sum of $m$ geometric distributions, each with a different probability?  It seems that the number of failures to advance one state has a geometric distribution, and you are asking for the distribution of number of failures before reaching state $m$.

Comment: A general symbolic result is certainly desired.  But what values of $k$ are of interest?  Small values say $k\leq 20$? Or very large values of $k$? I ask because if small values of $k$ would satisfy your objective, then a relatively simple algorithm is easy enough to construct.